# why does npm staging have multiple folders wit hthe same lib and version

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

When doing an npm install with the -ddd flag, I noticed the following output:

> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-238afce1
> (68114ms)
>
> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-512d1edc
> (67660ms)
>
> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-8116df1c
> (67770ms)
>
> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-0f96b965
> (68007ms)
>
> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-6a5eaafd
> (67783ms)
>
> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-e832871b
> (67894ms)
>
> npm sill extract rxjs@6.4.0 extracted to
> D:\DSTGIT\digital-advice\ciam-web-app\node_modules.staging\rxjs-394691af
> (68075ms)

I thought it would only do it once per version.
Any ideas?

Comment: `node.js-addon` is a tag for Node.JS C++ addons

Comment: my bad, fixed now, thanks.